# Having trouble with Text.BeforeDelimiter

Tags: powerquery, m

Any idea why this: `= Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", each Text.BeforeDelimiter("ABCDEFG","E"))`

Is giving me this: 
[image]

?

My expectation is that this would populate each cell in the column "Custom" with "ABCD". I've checked and rechecked the spelling. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function was recently added to Power BI Desktop (April 2017 update) and even more recently to Power Query in Excel. So probably you are using the function in an environment where it is not yet available.

If I copy and paste your code, it is working just fine (and as you expected).