# Expression.Error: The name 'Text.BeforeDelimiter' wasn't recognized. Excel 2016

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I have an excel "Add Column" from Power Query editor. My data looks like this,

```
26567-5698
51254-5458
6954-1545
45415
56541
5621
..
```

Some have 4 digits before `-` and some have 5 digits before `-`. For those values that have `-` in between, I like to extract the first part (before delimiter).

I tried the following,

```
if  
    Text.Length(Text.BeforeDelimiter([MyCol], "-")) = 4   
  then
    "0" & Text.Start([MyCol],4)
 else if  
     Text.Length(Text.BeforeDelimiter([MyCol], "-")) = 5   
  then 
     Text.Start([MyCol],5)
else
   [MyCol]
```

If the length before delimiter I am adding a `0` and first 4 digits. Otherwise, I want the first 5 digits.

When I do the above, I get the following error:

> Expression.Error: The name 'Text.BeforeDelimiter' wasn't recognized. 
>   Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-beforedelimiter) I am following.

I am using Excel 2016. I have been searching and could not find anything related to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble with Text.BeforeDelimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936040/having-trouble-with-text-beforedelimiter)

Comment: @AlexisOlson Any alternative ways to reach my goal in power query?

Comment: There are other ways, but are you unable to update your Excel? This should be rolled into Excel 2016 through normal updates by now.

Comment: @Wedge "This should be rolled into Excel 2016 through normal updates by now" I am using Excel 2016 and still an issue for now!

Comment: @Wedge would you be able to give a hint on other ways please? I was thinking of splitting the text by delimiter, but having a hard time taking the first part after splitting

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Excel 2016? Wedge is suggesting you are using an outdated version of it.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yes, I am using the latest version. Also, yesterday, I did a repair/update to my office 365. I think I am going to use `split column` and then use the splitted column's length to add `0` in front if it is 4 in length. For now, that is my workaround I guess! I'll make sure re-update my excel again!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a workaround with other text functions.

```
Left  = try Text.Start([MyCol], Text.PositionOf([MyCol], "-")) otherwise [MyCol]
Right = try Text.Range([MyCol], Text.Length([Left]) + 1) otherwise null
```