# Expression.Error for Text.InferNumberType wasn't recognized

Tags: powerquery, m

I've got a function where I want to determine if all the digits after the first are numbers.  To do so, I thought I could use Text.InferNumberType which, per [the documentation](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-infernumbertype), should raise an error if the text is not a number.

Here is my code snippet:

```
a= Text.Start(Argument,1),
b= Text.End(Argument, Text.Length(Argument) - 1),
c= try Text.InferNumberType(b) otherwise "FALSE" ,
```

Instead, I'm getting this Expression.Error which says:

> Expression.Error: the name `Text.InferNumberType` wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.

I literally copied and pasted the function name from the reference document, so I'm sure it's spelled correctly.

I'm using PowerQuery in Excel 2013. PowerQuery was installed about a week ago using the latest download from Microsoft. I did search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193394/4106771) - I'm wondering if this is a similar issue?  I don't see anything in the documentation though which says this function wouldn't be available in certain versions of power query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an older function that isn't supported in Excel 2013. I'd recommend a different function like [`Number.From`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-from) or [`Number.FromText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-fromtext), which have similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks again Alexis!  The documentation on powerquery is really poor in comparison to other Microsoft coding languages. I really hope they fix it to tell you if a function isn't compatible with a given version.  It's like the wild west trying to code in this language.

Answer (score 1):

The Number.From and Number.FromText functions are great if you want to return a number value. They will give an error if it's not possible.

However, if you want to return the 'type' of value, Text.InferNumberType returns it.

For more elaborate documentation on Text.InferNumberType you can make use of powerquery.how:

https://powerquery.how/text-infernumbertype/

Cheers,
Rick